# Как исправить ошибку: "Error when checking input: expected dense_1_input to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (60000, 28, 28)"

Tags: python, нейронные-сети, машинное-обучение, numpy, keras

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_1_input to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (60000, 28, 28)
```

учусь писать ии на python.

вот код

```
import keras
import numpy as np

model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(units=1, input_shape=[28, 28]))
model.compile(optimizer="sgd", loss="mean_squared_error")

mnist = keras.datasets.mnist
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, ytest) = mnist.load_data()

x_train = keras.utils.normalize(x_train, axis=1)
x_test = keras.utils.normalize(x_test, axis=1)

model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=3)

output = model.predict([x_test])

print(output)

e = input("\nPress enter to exit.")
```

Comment: `predict([x_test])` — очевидно, что надо передавать сам объект, а не массив, его содержащий. это то, что просто бросается в глаза, потому что непонятно, **где** именно у вас ошибка: вы почему-то решили скрыть от нас эту информацию.

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

Впервые вижу архитектуру НС, состоящую из единственного скрытого слоя и без выходного слоя ;-)

Не представляю как такая НС должна работать...

Воспользуйтесь [одной из проверенных архитектур для решения `MNIST` задачи](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/tree/master/examples), например несложной CNN:

```
import keras
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras import backend as K

batch_size = 128
num_classes = 10
epochs = 12

# input image dimensions
img_rows, img_cols = 28, 28

# the data, split between train and test sets
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
    x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], 1, img_rows, img_cols)
    x_test = x_test.reshape(x_test.shape[0], 1, img_rows, img_cols)
    input_shape = (1, img_rows, img_cols)
else:
    x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], img_rows, img_cols, 1)
    x_test = x_test.reshape(x_test.shape[0], img_rows, img_cols, 1)
    input_shape = (img_rows, img_cols, 1)

x_train = x_train.astype('float32')
x_test = x_test.astype('float32')
x_train /= 255
x_test /= 255
print('x_train shape:', x_train.shape)
print(x_train.shape[0], 'train samples')
print(x_test.shape[0], 'test samples')

# convert class vectors to binary class matrices
y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes)
y_test = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, num_classes)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3),
                 activation='relu',
                 input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
              optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adadelta(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train,
          batch_size=batch_size,
          epochs=epochs,
          verbose=1,
          validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
score = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=0)
print('Test loss:', score[0])
print('Test accuracy:', score[1])
```

результат:

```
...
Epoch 12/12
60000/60000 [==============================] - 109s 2ms/step - loss: 0.0290 - acc: 0.9912 - val_loss: 0.0271 - val_acc: 0.9911
Test loss: 0.027133107318412477
Test accuracy: 0.9911
```

Answer (score 0):

> ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_1_input to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (60000, 28, 28)

нужно изменить форму тензора, эта операция не используется в слоях нейронной сети, она приготавливает исходные данные для передачи в сеть.

Изменение формы тензора предполагает такое переупорядочивание строк и столбцов, чтобы привести его форму к заданной. Тензор и измененной формой имеет такое же кол-во элементов, что и исходный тензор. Пару примеров:

```
>>> x = np.array([[0., 1.],
                  [2., 3.],
                  [4., 5.]])
>>> print(x.shape)
(3, 2)
>>> x = x.reshape((6, 1))
>>> x
array([[ 0.],
       [ 1.],
       [ 2.],
       [ 3.],
       [ 4.],
       [ 5.]])
>>> x = x.reshape((2, 3))
>>> x
array([[ 0., 1., 2.],
       [ 3., 4., 5.]])
```

Есть особый случай изменения формы - транспонирование. Это преобразование матрицы, когда строки становятся столбцами, а столбцы - строками, то есть x[i,:] превращается в x[:,1]

А вот фикс вашего кода, но там действительно нужен выходной слой для минимальной сети с двумя ветвями (two-branch networks):

```
import keras
import numpy as np

mnist = keras.datasets.mnist
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

x_train = x_train.reshape(60000, 28 * 28)
x_test = x_test.reshape(10000, 28 * 28)
x_train = x_train.astype('float32') / 255
x_test = x_test.astype('float32') / 255

y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train)
y_test =  keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test)

model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu', input_shape=[28 * 28]))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
model.summary()


model.compile(optimizer="sgd", loss="mean_squared_error", metrics=['accuracy'])


model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=3, batch_size=32)

output = model.predict([x_test])
print(output)

scope = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test)
print('Test loss:', scope[0])
print('Test accuracy:', scope[1])

e = input("\nPress enter to exit.")
```